# Spy++ like program for viewing control values

Tags: windows, visual-studio, sniffing, spy++

I'd like to view and export the values of a combobox.  What program can I use to allow me to get the values in a control inside another application?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Do you have control of the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sysview](http://comrade.ownz.com/projects/sysview.html) does it, but it is not exactly easy to use

Edit: Another alternative; [SysExporter](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sysexp.html)